# How do I combine columns into one, and filter out NULLs?

Tags: sql

Here is my table. A list of ids with signup dates in columns newsletter, report, infographics.

[image]

I want to combine all those columns into one, without the NULLs

I've tried the following code

```
SELECT id, combined_column
FROM (
    SELECT id, CONCAT(newsletter, report, infographics) AS combined_column 
    FROM table
)
WHERE combined_column IS NOT NULL
```

But this just gives me a blank table. Is there a way to solve this? Thanks

Comment: What are you using? `Sql-Server, MySQL, etc.` And trying to `Concatenate` a `NULL` value may be the problem, you should look into converting `NULLS` to `empty strings` if you are going to `Concatenate` all the column values together.

Comment: Just for anyone's curiousity, I tested this in `Sql-Server 2014` and it returns all three rows in the outer select, I didn't even bother casting `Datetimes` to `varchars` and the `Concat` function still worked, maybe in `Sql-Server` it converts to string behind the scenes or something. Anyway, since you haven't specified what kind of database engine you are working with, that is all I can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `coalesce` which return the first not null value from the list (it you have more than one not null value in a row it'll still return the first one):

```
SELECT id, COALESCE(newsletter, report, infographics) AS combined_date
FROM t
WHERE COALESCE(newsletter, report, infographics) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want this?

```
select max(newsletter) as newsletter,
       max(report) as report,
       max(infographics) as infographics
from t;
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Answer may depend on what database you're using, so caveat lector.

Is it the case that only one column will be non-null, as in your sample?

Then something like:

```
SELECT id, COALESCE(newsletter, infographics, report) FROM my_table;
```

might work for you...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle, use `NVL` to replace `NULL` with empty string

```
SELECT id, 
   combined_column
FROM (
    SELECT id, 
         CONCAT(NVL(newsletter,''), NVL(report,''), NVL(infographics,'')) AS combined_column 
    FROM table
     )

WHERE combined_column is not NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT id, 
    CONCAT(newsletter, report, infographics) AS combined_column 
FROM table WHERE newsletter is NOT NULL and report is NOT NULL and infographics is NOT NULL